# Basic4Android Vibration pattern

Tags: design-patterns, vibration, basic4android

I'm trying to create an application that have different vibration patterns.

I've seen that the PhoneVibrate class has only a Vibrate(TimeMs as Long) function.
I've also seen that there also is another java function that supports patterns
(see here: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-vibrator/ )

Is it possible to use it on Basic4Android? How do I solve this problem?
Regards,

Nicola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code (requires Phone library and Reflection library):

```
Sub Process_Globals
    Dim pv As PhoneVibrate 'Required to add the Vibrate permission
End Sub

Sub Globals

End Sub
Sub Activity_Create(FirstTime As Boolean)
    Vibrate(500, 300)
    ToastMessageShow("Click anywhere to stop vibrate.", True)
End Sub

Sub Activity_Pause (UserClosed As Boolean)

End Sub
Sub Activity_Resume

End Sub

Sub Activity_Click
    CancelVibrate
End Sub

Sub Vibrate(On As Long, Off As Long)
    Dim r As Reflector
    r.Target = r.GetContext
    r.Target = r.RunMethod2("getSystemService", "vibrator", "java.lang.String")
    Dim pattern(2) As Long
    pattern(0) = On
    pattern(1) = Off
    r.RunMethod4("vibrate", Array As Object(pattern, 0), Array As String("[J", "java.lang.int"))
End Sub

Sub CancelVibrate
    Dim r As Reflector
    r.Target = r.GetContext
    r.Target = r.RunMethod2("getSystemService", "vibrator", "java.lang.String")
    r.RunMethod("cancel")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Erel. I'll try your solution. Do you plan to add full Vibrate functions on next release of Basic4Android?

Comment: The above method is exactly like the full vibrate method available in Android API.

Comment: Yes, I mean a B4A function instead using Reflection.